# How do I find 'Remove Doubles' in 2.8?

Tags: mesh, interface

I looked it up and 'remove doubles' should be under Mesh in 2.8.

[image: no remove doubles]

I can't find it.

Comment: it's now alt M > Merge By Distance

Answer (score 3):

Remove Doubles is now renamed as **Merge By Distance**.
and it is located under

> Mesh> Clean Up > Merge By Distance

and

> Vertex > Merge Vertices > By Distance

`(in Edit mode )`

Shortcut key is **Alt+M** > **By Distance**