# Sculpting leads to tear in center (blender 2.8)

Tags: sculpting, sculpt

When attempting to sculpt on my current project, the center of the mesh distorts, as seen below.

[image]
Attempting to use the crease tool on the mesh does nothing UNTIL I get to the center, where the above change takes place. I tried several other tools and I get the same (or similar) results. Let it be noted, too, that I'm using a mirror modifier, and that center seam is where both sides meet, in case that's relevant.

[image]

Here is the .blend file, if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Mirror modifier creates double points in mesh. Regularly, you will want to remove double points, especially before rendering. Double points sometime cause rips in mesh.

Rule of thumb, always remove doubles before ever rendering. 
Just select entire mesh in Edit Mode and remove doubles. Hotkey for "Remove Doubles" is changed in version 2.8. See links below

[How do I find 'Remove Doubles' in 2.8? [duplicate]](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/141172/how-do-i-find-remove-doubles-in-2-8)

[2.8 remove doubles has changed to Merge by Distance](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/123185/2-8-remove-doubles-has-changed-to-merge-by-distance)

Answer (score 0):

first of all, you must apply all your modifiers before going to sculpt mode, since you have a good base mesh, I recommend you to apply the mirror modifier, and replace the subdivision with the multiresolution modifier, which allows you to sculpt in a good amount of detail, give it 4 or 5 subdivision and everything should work just fine for you. Regards.

Comment: Jeez, that's so simple! That did the trick, thanks. Now I just need to figure out how to, you know... sculpt. Cheers!

Comment: Practice, Practice, Practice.

Also a must watch chanels:
YanSculpts
https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCfjswDVU0XHyBN7UFG0Mi5Q

Zacharias Reinhardt
https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCWWybvw9jnpOdJq_6wTHryA

Julien Kaspar
https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC77wk1coLw9pXQiFl_Who1A