# Remove Doubles in Blender 2.93.1 Not available? How to remove double vertices

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves

I was creating Bowling Ball Pin with bezier curves when i spinned the curves to make the pin out of it there are some double or overlapping vertices which i want to remove but i am unable to find remove double vertices option there. Is there any alternative option? Please don'tr recommend one by one selection and merge to center option. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Merge by distance

Comment: as Allen Simpson says it is now Alt M > Merge by Distance (or Vertex panel > Merge > By Distance)

Comment: It helped, Thank you guys!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Blender 2.80 Remove double vertices option gone](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/139733/blender-2-80-remove-double-vertices-option-gone)  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/123185/2-8-remove-doubles-has-changed-to-merge-by-distance   https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/141172/how-do-i-find-remove-doubles-in-2-8